# Need a php based filemanager with support for extracting RAR/ZIP?

Tags: php, rar, file-management

Is there any php based filemanager with RAR support that I can host on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Mollify supports ZIP files:

http://www.mollify.org/features.php

Haven't tried it with RAR.  You mention ZIP in the question title so perhaps this will be OK?